# Babel module loading techniques

Tags: module, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm writing most new code with es6/babel/jspm. But module loading is not yet standardized so run into troubles with other team members using webpack, browserify etc.

This leads me to ask just what *are* the various workflows for babel module loading? Any pointers? Pros/Cons? Basically I need a way to at least provide the alternatives to our team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using gulp + browserify but switched to webpack.
reasons:

- performance
- smaller output
- less dependencies (webpack has minification and sourcemaps built in)

webpack examples (babel6)

https://github.com/glued/harp-babel/blob/master/webpack.config.js

https://github.com/glued/harp-babel/blob/master/webpack.production.config.js

gulp example  (babel6)

https://github.com/glued/harp-babel/blob/babel-gulp-v6/gulpfile.babel.js